# What is the name of this ancient means of identification based on broken objects?

Tags: identification, classical-antiquity, bronze-age

I'm gathering data about the origins of identification/authentication means. I remember having read about a way of identifying a friend, during the bronze age. Maybe during classical antiquity also.

It was by using a rock, or a pottery / ceramic shard that you broke in two or more pieces. Joining the fragments served as a means to identify the holder. I remember this was used in ancient Iberia (this very name suggests a Roman source) but I could be mistaken.

This practice is described in several local legends, notably around the Pyrenean area (mountain range separating Spain and France), but from a much later age (medieval age, starting from the Xth century) and by using torn papers or broken jewelry. Such a legend, as an example, is the legend of Bos de Benac ([English version (translated)](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bos_de_B%25C3%25A9nac) and [French original version](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bos_de_B%C3%A9nac#:%7E:text=Synopsis%20de%20la%20l%C3%A9gende,-Le%20seigneur%20a&text=Contraint%20de%20suivre%20le%20roi,(Cordier)%20coup%C3%A9%20en%20deux.)).

The relevant excerpt is : "*The Lord married a young woman full of virtues. Forced to follow the king to the crusade, he leaves his wife by agreeing to a sign of recognition: marriage contract (Bladé) torn in two, ring or diamond (Cordier) cut in half.*".

My understanding is that this practice echoes an ancient practice, the one I'm seeking to identify.

Is there a name for this specific practice? I know about the "bulla", and the notion of "shibboleth", but this is not the same usage and I believe there is a term for and studies about this subject.

Comment: somewhat related https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/43349/how-were-state-level-suspects-identified-prior-to-photography

Comment: "The commonplace symbolon, a token broken in two such that the bearers of each half could recognise a relationship with the bearer of the other even if the bearers were personally unknown to each other, makes a number of appearances in Greek tragedy" ([pdf](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/arts/classics/research/dept_projects/tcam/events/athens/workshoptokens1211prasentation.pdf))

Comment: Research *tally stick* for examples of how this means of confirmation was also used to document contracts.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is a multipurpose generic name for such a divided/broken identification technique but there is an example from many centuries past that has survived into modern maritime practice.

The contract to hire a vessel is called a "charter party" as evolved from the Latin *carta partita*, or torn/divided charter/letter. In pre-modern times, to authenticate the authorities of the shipowner and of the ship charterer/lessee two identical copies of the full terms of the contract were inscribed on the same document/parchment which was cut or torn in two. The ship owner and the ship charterer each retained one copy and, when the two copies were joined together showing a perfect match between the torn edges, the rights of the respective parties could be determined. At a minimum this could serve to impede a ship charterer from selling a vessel which it possessed only by temporary rental but fraud could be attempted by an unscrupulous charterer. By the peripatetic nature of sea going vessels the application of the laws of a specific jurisdiction was impractical, resulting in the development over time of international practices that evolved into admiralty law, the first form of international law which came to be adopted by sea going countries, aspects of which were eventually codified in international conventions.

Comment: I believe this is similar to *indentures*, where the agreement between master/apprentice was recorded on two halves of paper, which matched when joined - ie *indented*.